# c++ redistributable error

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, itunes, c++

I'm trying to install Itunes on a  Windows 7 64 bit

[image]

I've seen similar questions on the web, most from 2010, I need new solutions, I saw many solutions, I need a definitive one, I can't try this and that, so many solutions on the web, so confusing.

**Edit**

I can confirm that the issue has something to do with C++, after I tried installing `VC++ 2005 redistributable` I get

[image]

Comment: There's no definitive magic spell to solve all computer problems. First try what you've found. You'll never know if a solution is correct in your case if you won't try it yourself.

Comment: Reinstall the current release version of `VC++ 2005 redistributable`

Comment: @gronostaj so many solutions say install updates, some say install c++ some reinstalled windows 7, thats pure madness, my computer is not a testing lab

Comment: @Fischer Here on Super User we expect users to at least try something first. It's not always crystal clear what's wrong with a computer. Why do you think people give different answers? They do so because they are trying different things until one works for that specific case. That's how troubleshooting works. Every answer has some reasons behind it, if it doesn't work in your case it doesn't mean somebody typed it just to make your life harder. It's your role to verify solutions.

Comment: @gronostaj true, I've been on SO network long enough to know just that, but this subject in particular has too many different possible solutions, it's frustrating

Comment: @Ramhound please read my edit

Comment: The `HRESULT` code you're getting translates to `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED`, which means "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it." Additionally, error `1935` (`0x78F` in hexadecimal) is `ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FIREWALL_FAILED`, described as "Logon failure: The machine you are logging on to is protected by an authentication firewall. The specified account is not allowed to authenticate to the machine." Make sure the **Windows Module Installer** service (`msiserver`) is not disabled.

Comment: @and31415 sorry for the late reply, thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick analysis

The `HRESULT` code you're getting translates to `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED`, which means:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
>
> <sub>Source: [Win32 Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx)</sub>

Additionally, error `1935` (`0x78F` in hexadecimal) is `ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FIREWALL_FAILED`, described as:

> Logon failure: The machine you are logging on to is protected by an authentication firewall. The specified account is not allowed to authenticate to the machine.
>
> <sub>Source: [Win32 Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx)</sub>

Make sure the **Windows Module Installer** service (`msiserver`) is not disabled. By default, it should be set to **Manual**.

## References

- [Win32 Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx)
- [Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC HRESULT: 0x80070422](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/d5299571-de27-461a-aa41-877917b7a58b/microsoftvc80mfcloc-hresult-0x80070422)